# Approach to deferred events implementation

Tags: javascript, promise

Are there any standard approaches to implementation of deferred events? For example,

```
service.on('before-file-delete', function(event){
    //here I want to show non-blocking confirm to user, wait for his response
    //and then either call event.preventDefault() or not
})
```

My current implementation is pretty basic:

```
service.on('before-file-delete', function(event, file){
   event.deferredResult = showConfirm().then(function(result) {
        if (result === 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
   });
})
```

And inside service's emitter:

```
var event = emit('before-file-delete', file);
event.deferredResult.then(function () { 
      if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
      // file is not deleted until deferredResult is resolved
      file.delete();
}});
```

But I'm wondering if there's any standart implementation?

Comment: if `showConfirm` is asynchronous, would `event.preventDefault()` do anything at all useful?

Comment: You cannot call `preventDefault()` on an event after it has occured.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I renamed the event to `before-file-delete`. As you can see from the last extract of code, the file is not being deleted until `deferredResult` is resolved

Comment: @Bergi, is events mechanism not suitable for such task at all?